# How can I tell AUCTeX to turn off math mode for the argument of shortintertext?

Tags: math-mode, emacs, auctex

I would like to have AUCTeX turn off math mode for the argument of the `shortintertext` command from the `mathtools` package. I customized the variable `texmathp-tex-command` to add the following line to my `init.el` file:

```lisp
'(texmathp-tex-commands (quote (("shortintertext" arg-off))))
```

However when I enter a dollar in the argument of `shortintertext` I get the following message in the minibuffer:

```
Math mode started with `align` cannot be closed with dollar
```

which indicates that the argument is still in math mode.

I am using Emacs 24.3 with package install of auctex.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)  check to see if auctex has a definition for `\intertext`.  if it does, then `\shortintertext` should be treated the same way.

Comment: Yes, I set the condition for shortintertext to be the same as for intertext in texmathp.el in the AUCTeX distribution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if auctex has a definition for `\intertext`, then `\shortintertext` should be treated the same way.